# NN gets stuck and np.exp overflow

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, nlp

I'm facing a problem with a simple neural network. I have sparse vectors as input which represents movie reviews. I generated these vectors with sklearn's CountVectorizer. The size of each vector is 5000. 
After a few iterations ( depends on how many reviews I use ), I get a warning: 
Overflow encountered in np.exp, which is part of my sigmoid function.
A few iterations later the neural network gets stuck and produces always the same error value 
I found out, that the np.exp-warning was caused by big values after the multiplication of syn1 and l1 in the forward propagation.

 I tried to normalize values in different layers of the net, but then
it got stuck again after a few iterations. 

Can anyone help me and tell me what is wrong in my code?

Thank you for your attention.

```
def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1 / ( 1 + np.exp( -x ) )
    return output

def sigmoid_output_to_derivate(x):
    return x * ( 1 - x )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("train_data_20.pkl", "rb") as fid:
        train_data_features = pickle.load( fid )
    with open("train_labels_20.pkl", "rb") as fid_train:
        train_labels = pickle.load( fid_train )

    with open("test_data_20.pkl", "rb") as fid_test:
        test_data_features = pickle.load( fid_test )
    with open("test_labels_20.pkl","rb") as fid_l:
        test_labels = pickle.load( fid_l )

    x = train_data_features[:2500]
    y = np.reshape( train_labels[:2500], (-1,1))


    np.random.seed(1)
    syn0 = 2*np.random.random((5000,6000))-1
    syn1 = 2*np.random.random((6000,1))-1

    for i in range(1000):
        l0 = x
        #l0 = l0 /  np.linalg.norm(l0)
        l1 = sigmoid( np.dot(l0,syn0) )
        l2 = sigmoid( np.dot(l1,syn1) )

        l2_error = y - l2

        error_mean = np.mean( np.abs( l2_error ) )
        print( "Error: ", str(error_mean ))

        l2_delta = l2_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivate(l2)

        l1_error = np.dot(l2_delta, syn1.T )
        l1_delta = l1_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivate(l1)

        syn1 += np.dot( l1.T, l2_delta )
        syn0 += np.dot( l0.T, l1_delta )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a numerically safe way to compute the sigmoid function. Basically, you need to have separate cases depending on if x is bigger than or less than zero. See the code at the link below.

http://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/